# GitHub API Download Link expires before it hits the limit

Tags: github, github-actions, github-api

When I do get Download Link usining GitHub API and I want to download artifact it gets straight to the `Artifact has expired`.

```bash
echo "ALLMODS_URL = $(curl -v -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" -H "Authorization: token ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}" -L "https://api.github.com/repos/repo/repo/actions/artifacts/124384712/zip")"
curl -v -O $ALLMODS_URL
```

The Github Log:

```bash
+ curl -v -H Accept: application/vnd.github+json -H Authorization: token *** -L https://api.github.com/repos/repo/repo/actions/artifacts/124384712/zip
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 140.82.114.5:443...
* Connected to api.github.com (140.82.114.5) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
*  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
} [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [512 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
{ [122 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
{ [19 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
{ [2456 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
{ [79 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
{ [36 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
} [1 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
} [36 bytes data]
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Francisco; O=GitHub, Inc.; CN=*.github.com
*  start date: Mar 16 00:00:00 2022 GMT
*  expire date: Mar 16 23:59:59 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "api.github.com" matched cert's "*.github.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=DigiCert Inc; CN=DigiCert TLS Hybrid ECC SHA384 2020 CA1
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
} [5 bytes data]
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x400008b650)
} [5 bytes data]
> GET /repos/repo/repo/actions/artifacts/124384712/zip HTTP/2
> Host: api.github.com
> user-agent: curl/7.74.0
> accept: application/vnd.github+json
> authorization: token ***
> 
{ [5 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
{ [57 bytes data]
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Newsession Ticket (4):
{ [57 bytes data]
* old SSL session ID is stale, removing
{ [5 bytes data]
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 100)!
} [5 bytes data]
< HTTP/2 410 
< server: GitHub.com
< date: Mon, 24 Oct 2022 17:48:11 GMT
< content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< content-length: 134
< x-github-media-type: github.v3; format=json
< x-ratelimit-limit: 1000
< x-ratelimit-remaining: 999
< x-ratelimit-reset: 1666637291
< x-ratelimit-used: 1
< x-ratelimit-resource: core
< access-control-expose-headers: ETag, Link, Location, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Used, X-RateLimit-Resource, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval, X-GitHub-Media-Type, X-GitHub-SSO, X-GitHub-Request-Id, Deprecation, Sunset
< access-control-allow-origin: *
< strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
< x-frame-options: deny
< x-content-type-options: nosniff
< x-xss-protection: 0
< referrer-policy: origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin
< content-security-policy: default-src 'none'
< vary: Accept-Encoding, Accept, X-Requested-With
< x-github-request-id: 0400:1C3C:8DAF00E:12259BA9:6356CFDB
< 
{ [134 bytes data]

100   134  100   134    0     0    429      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   448
* Connection #0 to host api.github.com left intact
+ echo ALLMODS_URL = {
  "message": "Artifact has expired",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/actions#download-an-artifact"
}
ALLMODS_URL = {
  "message": "Artifact has expired",
  "documentation_url": "https://docs.github.com/rest/reference/actions#download-an-artifact"
}
+ curl -v -O
curl: no URL specified!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

PS:Have been trying to use action there for downloading artifacts but it fails for me because `Permission Denied`

Comment: When was the artifact uploaded, and with what retention?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Sine this workflow takes a lot of time. Artiface was uploaded right about over 1h ago. Artifact was uploaded using https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact